# ActionBarSherlock Tabs with Fragments not correctly

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I've started a small application that I'm modeling after ABS: Fragments -> Tabs and Pager.

In my app, I've created a main activity that looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
TabHost mTabHost;
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
ConfigDBHelper sily_db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this,mTabHost,mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"),
            MainSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
    /*
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
      mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
     */

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
```

The code, eventually, will contain multiple tabs - but for now, I've created only 1.

My activity_main layout file is fragment_tabs_pager.xml from ABS renamed.  My MainSupport is FragmentStackSupport.java but renamed.

When I run my application, instead of seeing a "tab" at the top of the screen, I'm seeing the one and only tab in the MIDDLE of the view - covering both the fragment_stack.xml layout AND the hello_world.xml layout.

My suspicion is I've got a missing or incorrect directive someplace, but am unsure where.  Especially as I skipped past the SimpleList.java module that is in the samples.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using ABS tabs then no need to use TabHost(Deprecated).

Comment: It appears the underlying problem with my copy of ABS was it's inability to find class files and other resources using the mechanism the ABS author used.  This was caused by me trying to use snippets of code without understanding the whole of the ABS samples.  We can chalk this one up to *user error*!  lol